# JS generated code readable for screen readers

Tags: javascript, html, screen-readers

I'm trying to understand and figure out if the code generated by JavaScript will provide info for screenreaders like regular HTML tags. I'll show you what I mean.

I want my `div1` text to change relatively.

```
<script>
function changeText()
{
 document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = '<input type="button" onclick="changeText2()" value="Change Text2" />';
}
function changeText2()
{
 document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = '<input type="button" onclick="changeText()" value="Change Text" />';
}
</script>
<div id="div1">
<input type='button' onclick='changeText()' value='Change Text'/>
</div>
```

It does the trick and I'm very excited by that, because I'm very new to coding, but I want my site to be adoptable for blind people who use screenreaders. When I checked the generated HTML code, the code does not change by pressing the button, so I assume the screenreaders will be reading this first button(in the HTML layout) without paying any attention for the generated code.

If I'm right, what can I do about it? Is there any way to change text like that.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Accessible Rich Internet Applications (WAI-ARIA).

Comment: May  you please be a little bit more directly, because there's a lot of information.

Comment: If you mean tags and alike, that's not an issue. I know about them. The problem is that the generated by JS html text will replace visually the text, but yet it won't be accessible. I think... I don't know if it will be or not, but this is the problem here.

Comment: Use aria live: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions